# Populate Dictionary During Compile with Foreach File in Source?

Tags: c#, compilation

Ok, so this may not be possible, but I am wondering if it is possible to create a dictionary like this:

```
public static class TableList
{
    public static Dictionary<string, JObject> Tables = new Dictionary<string, JObject>();
    public static JObject GetTable(string ReturnTable)
    {
        Tables = new Dictionary<string, JObject>();
        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(FolderPath, "*.cs");
        foreach (string FileName in files)
        {
            string FormattedFilename = FileName;
            FormattedFilename = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(FormattedFilename);
            FormattedFilename = char.ToUpper(FormattedFilename[0]) + FormattedFilename.Substring(1);
            Tables.Add(FileName, TableDefinitions.FormattedFilename.TableDef());

        }

        if (Tables.ContainsKey(ReturnTable))
        {
            return Tables[ReturnTable];

        }
        else
        {
            return TableDefinitions.GenericTable.TableDef(ReturnTable);

        }
    }
}
```

I have a lot of configuration files (100+) in a single directory of the source code and the only thing missing to automate getting them to work is the line:

```
Tables.Add(file, TableDefinitions.File.TableDef());
```

I can manually do each line, but I love to automate things where possible.

Comment: Could you explain better what is the problem with the code above?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but try to avoid `ContainsKey`. `TryGetValue` will do what you need without two hash lookups.

Comment: Sorry for not being more clear. I changed the source a little. In this section: `TableDefinitions.FormattedFilename.TableDef()`, it won't insert `FormattedFilename` as part of the object.

Comment: Sorry but still unclear. What is TableDefinitions? Does it have a property named FormattedFilename and the type of this property has a method called TableDef?

Comment: Obviously `FormattedFileName` is a string, which does not have any `TableDef`. But i´m unsure what OP expects here.

Comment: TableDefinitions is a Namespace that holds all the configuration files for the database I am working on. As I work out the configurations needed, a configuration file is automatically generated and saved into that directory, but it doens't update the source code to add that new item to the Dictionary. I am not certain this is possible, but I have learned to ask before assuming it is impossible.

Comment: I think you're saying that you want a line of code for each file in a directory.  Is there a reason you want to add lines to the code rather than just look at the directory at run time?  Are the config files available at run time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you want to look at a directory at the time you compile, then create code based on that.

You can use Design time T4 text templates to create code just before compilation.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/modeling/code-generation-and-t4-text-templates?view=vs-2017#design-time-t4-text-templates

**EDIT**

I haven't messed with these templates before, so I thought I'd give a whack at your particular problem.

In your `.tt` file you can use this code:

```
<#@ template debug="true" hostspecific="true" language="C#" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Core" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Windows.Forms" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Linq" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Text" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.IO" #>
<#@ output extension=".cs" #>

using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Sandbox
{
    public class TestClass
    {
      public static List<string> GetFiles()
      {
          List<string> filenames = new List<string>();
          <#
          string path = @"C:\Test";
          foreach (var x in Directory.GetFiles(path))
          {#>
            filenames.Add(@"<#=x#>");
          <#}#>
          return filenames;

      }
    }
}
```

That will generate this output in a `.cs` file:

using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Collections.Generic;

```
  namespace Sandbox
  {
    public class TestClass
    {
      public static List<string> GetFiles()
      {
          List<string> filenames = new List<string>();
          filenames.Add(@"C:\Test\A.txt");
          filenames.Add(@"C:\Test\B.txt");
          return filenames;
      }
    }
  }
```

Then you can call that from your main code:

```
var fileList = Sandbox.TestClass.GetFiles();
```

Comment: Thank you MikeH, that was just what I needed. The configuration files are not available at runtime so this is perfect.